# onBlur() function does not work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I developed a table with PHP. Table data comes from a MySQL database. One of the fields of the table is editable. I set an `onBlur` listener for this editable field, so that after editing, the edited data will be sent to the MySQL table. The problem is that the `onBlur` function is not working.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "??????";
$password = "???????";
$dbname = "????????";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM beacons";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Major number</th>
            <th>Minor number</th>
            <th>Client</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Link to ad</th>
            <th>Attachment</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    foreach ($result as $k=>$v) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>" .$row["major"]. "</td>
                    <td>" .$row["minor"]. "</td>
                    <td>" .$row["client"]. "</td>
                    <td contenteditable=\"true\" onBlur=\"saveToDatabase(this,'geolocation', $result[$k][\"id\"])\" onClick=\"showEdit(this)\" > ".$row["geolocation"]. "</td>
                    <td>" .$row["linktoadd"].  "</td>
                    <td>" .$row["attacment"] . "</td>
                    <td></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>
    </table>";
}
else {
    echo "no results";
}
```

My JavaScript code:

```
function showEdit(editableObj) {
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
} 

function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "updatebeacon.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
        success: function(data) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
        }
   });
}
```

This is the PHP code that implements database functions:

```
<?php
class DB_Functions_Beacon 
{
    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * update beacon(link and geo and attachment)
     * returns user details
     */
    public function updateBeacon($column, $editable, $id) 
    {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $id2=$id;
        $geolocation=$column;
        $geolocation2=$editable;

        $sql ="UPDATE beacons SET $geolocation=$geolocation2,  WHERE id=$id2";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Another one:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions_Beacons.php';
$db = new DB_Functions_Beacons();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['column']) && isset($_POST['editval']) && isset($_POST['id'])) 
{
    // receiving the post params
    $editable = $_POST['editable'];
    $column = $_POST['column'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

        $beacon = $db->updateBeacon($column,$editval,$id);
        if ($beacon) {
            // user updated successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            echo json_encode($response);
        } 
        else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
} 
else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters  is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: come one dude!! at least comment why did you down vote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

1. `OnBlur` will only get called on an `input` or `textarea`.. (maybe other elements, need to check the documentation). You're asking the browser to call `onBlur` on the `<td>` element, this event will never happen.
2. Seeing as you're using jQuery, why don't you set up a callback on the blur of the element?

First, you will need to make the `<td>` into an `<input class="editable">`, use `.click(function(..))`

Then, use `.blur()` or `.on('blur', function()` to callback the blur event.

```
$("td.geo").click(function()
{
    $(this).html('<input class="editable" value="'+$(this).html()+'"/>');
    setEditable();
});

function setEditable()
{
    $( ".editable" ).on( "blur", function() { 
       // saveToDatabase(... 
    }
});
```

This will clean up your HTML significantly.

EDIT:

Also, make sure you clean your Database Model, it looks injectable from here.

Comment: i do not want my table field to be blank(using input makes it blank -) i want it to be editable, so how can I use your solution with this explanation?

Comment: It won't be blank if you do a bit more work. `<input class="editable" value="'.$row["geolocation"]." .../>` for example. Or you could get the jQuery to populate the value from the table. Either way, `onBlur` does not get called on a `<td>` element, it must be done on an editable element.

Comment: Or you can render the input field on click over the `td` content

Comment: I've added some more code to demonstrate how this could be done. There needs to be a little more work in the `onBlur` call where you save the content and return the UX to the original state.